# How do we punctuate an abbreviation followed by a colon?

Tags: punctuation

When making bullet points of details about something, do we punctuate the abbreviation?

Is it this way?

> The details of the Vehicle are given below:
>
> 1. Vehicle Chassis No.: [dot and colon with no space]
> 2. Vehicle Chassis No. [dot only]
> 3. Vehicle Chassis No. : [dot and colon with space]

Which one them is right?

Comment: I have always seen bullet points preceded by a leading statement ending with a colon and no space. So the first option would be correct.

Comment: @MamtaD so there is no need to put a space between the colon and dot after the abbreviation "no"?

Comment: 4. Vehicle Chassis No: [colon - space]

Comment: I agree with @MamtaD – I think #3 is the worst of your options here. This is a matter of style, so it's not a matter of one of them being "right." If you look hard enough, you might even find conflicting guidance in different style guides. The most important thing is to **be consistent**; that is, do it the same way throughout your document.

Comment: Could you write some full sentence examples? I can't tell why you need to use a colon (indicating a list) when a "Vehicle Chassis No." should be unique.

Comment: @user3169 - My guess is that this is for a form, not a prose sentence.

Comment: @J.R. My idea too, but that should be in the question. I think how formatting of the form is done is more relevant here than punctuation rules in regular writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abbreviated form `No.` comes from the word 'numero'. Note the **'dot'** after the letter 'o'. It's 'No.' *(with dot)* and **not** 'No' *(without dot)*.

Now, the pattern you follow seems to be *listing* the credential of a vehicle. Generally, we put colons in such context. For instance...

> Name: Mr. Narendra Modi 
>  Age: 65 years 
>  Address: xyz...
>  and so on...

As you see that such listing happens with the colon **and** the dot is indeed necessary to abbreviate *numero* (to avoid reading it '*No* - negation'), it'd be dot and colon with no space in between.

About space:

You do not put a space before a colon, but you do need a space after one.  Source: http://www.learnenglish.de/punctuation/punctuationtext.html#colon

So, you may write like:

> Vehicle Owner: Mr. Tim Cook 
>  Vehicle Chassis **No.:** XYZ1234ABC 
>  Vehicle Type: SUV 
>  and so on...

Comment: The OP never asked anything about spacing **after** column name. All 3 of the examples he has posted **already include** that space. His question was related to space between/after dot and colon.

Comment: Why was the answer deleted to make some minor modifications? All the constructive comments given earlier below the original answer are lost. :-(

Comment: The comments were constructive but **after**  the 'edit', they became irrelevant. The comments talked about the 'reference' in the answer which no longer existed. Comments are to be kept when they are relevant to the question/answer as they are. If you see, the first comment of yours which still *applies* to my answer is kept. @MamtaD

Answer (score 0):

If I am sending email updates for a play named "Into the Woods Junior", I would send it with the subject line, "Into the Woods Jr.: Box Office & Scheduling Update"
I think the colon should come after an abbreviation but to be honest I was never really sure.

Comment: If you could provide a authoritative reference, I think that would strength your answer. You can [edit] your post to make improvements at any time.